# How to fix the function issue while allowing it to be dynamic?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

Let's say i'm calling a function given the following arguments

```
Function(char1, char2, char3, char4, Number)
```

where the first 4 terms represent `chars` and the last is an `int`, i might add more chars so the function can't be static . The main function will start like

```
def Function(*args):
  table_line = ""
  for x in range(Number/2):
```

but by giving the Function args it no longer knows that it should use the supplied argument number in that third line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `number` as the first argument:

```
def func(number, *char):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python3.x (which you're now not, as you mentioned in the comments), you could unpack your `args` using `*` iterable unpacking, before using them:

```
def function(*args):
    *chars, number = args
    ...
```

It works like this:

```
In [8]: *a, b = (1, 2, 3, 4)

In [9]: a
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]

In [10]: b
Out[10]: 4
```

Every element in `args` *except the last* is sent to `chars`, which now becomes a `list`. You may now use the `number` variable as a separate variable.

Comment: Forgot to mention, python2.7 , that method isn't supported on python<3.

Comment: @Tim Uff, those details are important. Go for what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843396/4909087) suggests then.

Comment: Done thanks for the time you've taken to answer tho.